# How to force UI update when capacitor app goes to background on android

Tags: android, angular, capacitor

Using Capacitor's [appStateChange](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/app#addlistener) event, we're making our app auto-lock, requiring the user to enter a pincode when re-opening the app. This works, but as soon as the app goes to the *background*, the app's screen seems to freeze on android, postponing the actual navigation to the pin-login screen until the app becomes active again. This way, the last screen is still visible for a short moment when the user brings the app to the foreground again, while the redirect is performed, which is quit ugly. Is there a way to force an update of the app's screen, and completing the redirect (or perform some other visual update to the UI).

We already tried using Angular's [Ngzone](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone), and Capacitor's [Background Task Plugin](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/background-task) but no luck so far.

Comment: Hey, did you figure this out? Please share your solution because I'm facing a similar problem